# Is it possible to uninstall Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, since the latest updates provide a different Ubuntu and SUSE app?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

If it is, how do I safely remove the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows application while leaving a working Ubuntu and OpenSUSE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `lxrun /uninstall /full` in (e.g.) Windows Powershell with administrative privileges will remove Bash on Ubuntu while leaving your new app-based Ubuntu installation untouched.

Comment: lxrun command not found (see other answers...)

Answer (score 15):

**TLDR**

```
wsl --unregister Legacy
```

**Explanation**

I believe [Christan Davén's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1389786/749435) just removes the shortcut from the start menu, but does not actually remove the WSL (you will still be able to run the WSL by executing `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` and find all of your files and installed apps as you left them).

[Silviu's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1264398/749435) is correct. However, if you've upgraded to the *Windows 10 Fall Creators Update* the `lxrun /uninstall /full` command will not be available anymore and you should instead run `wsl --unregister Legacy`.

A third option is to run `wslconfig /u Legacy` (try this if you are not using Windows Version 1903 or higher).

**Source**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-legacy#uninstallingremoving-the-legacy-distro

Comment: `wsl --unregister Ubuntu`

Answer (score 11):

Since `lxrun` was deprecated and removed in the *Windows 10 April 2018 Update* (see [Command Reference for Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference)), the only way for me to get rid of "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" was:

1. Remove Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) via the Control Panel
2. Restart the computer
3. Try to start "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"
4. Agree to remove the shortcut
5. Re-install WSL
6. Restart the computer

Hat tip to [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/261188/how-to-uninstall-or-reinstall-windows-10s-ubuntu-bash-shell/):

> If you’d like to remove the bash.exe tool and the Windows Subsystem for Linux from your computer completely, you’ll need to revisit the “Turn Windows Features On or Off” dialog in the Control Panel.
>
> To find it, open the Control Panel and head to Programs > Turn Windows Features On or Off.
>
> Uncheck the “Windows Subsystem for Linux” option here and click OK. Windows will uninstall the Windows Subsystem for Linux, bash.exe, and lxrun.exe commands. You can always revisit the Windows Features dialog to reinstall them in the future.